# Exporting separate files of streets from MID/MID which cover district

Tags: mapinfo, mif

I have MID/MIF that describes 80 streets of the district and I want to have separate pairs of MID/MID for each street from the original MID/MID.

I can save a copy of district MID/MID and delete all but one street and save it, but maybe it could be made automatically?

Here is original MID/MIF:

[image: Origila MID/MIF]

so I need separate MID/MIF for each table entry.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to solve some other problem that could probably be solved differently - you should be able to iterate through the streets in the input file

Comment: Iterate through the streets? Didn't find such option in MapInfo yet

Comment: perhaps if you tell us what you are trying to do we can help you better

Comment: This can be done in MapBasic, which is sold separately. You could also import it into any open source system, or even parse the MID/MIF files in your scripting language of choice. All of this requires actual programming.

Comment: What I am trying to do: Have separated MId/MIF pairs for each street from the original MID/MIF

Comment: Have you solved your problem?